# 'podman push --digestfile=' creates an empty digest file

Tags: macos, podman

I'm using Podman (v 4.9.0) to build and push an image to the registries (Amazon ECR, DockerHub). Since the Podman image digest is differ to the registry digest (see [discussion](https://github.com/containers/podman/issues/14779)), I added the `--digestfile=Digestfile` option to the push command to get the image digest:

```
podman push --digestfile=Digestfile imageID registry.example.com/repository:tag
```

But the command above creates an empty digest file. Moreover, there is no warning or errors in the command output.

Comment: That Podman creates an empty digest file does not seem to match the documentation of the __--digestfile__ option https://docs.podman.io/en/stable/markdown/podman-push.1.html#digestfile-digestfile  Sounds like a bug to me.

Comment: Yes, it does, but I would ask if anybody faced the same problem and coped to solve it. Unfortunately I have found nothing regarding the ‘digestfile’ option except very fiew GitHub issues and the official documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I've found that `--digestfile` option is not compatible with MacOS (it works fine with Linux), cause the terminal on Mac [remotely](https://podman.io/docs/installation#macos) communicates with the podman service running in the Machine VM and the option is not available for the remote interaction.